# Synchronize LDAP servers with DSML format

Tags: ldap, dsml

Is it possible to synchronize two LDAP servers with the DSML protocol instead of ldif?
We have a firewall between our 2 servers and the only authorized protocol/payload is http over xml.

We had a look at a DSML gateway, but it does not seem to be well suited for our need here

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, it's software.  DSML is more of a representation of LDAP in XML, and it's therefore possible to send DSML queries to a server to replay some operations that happened in the first one. But I don't know of any server that can log or dump the changes they receive into DSML queries to replay later.